# How to find a vector field by Gauss's divergence theorem.

Tags: divergence-operator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83Qqy.png)I know how to find the value by knowing the vector filed but I want to find out if you can do it the other way round
an example would be
double integral over closed loop F ds = 5

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. Please format the equations using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of attaching URLs to images.

Comment: but do you still know how to do the question

Comment: If you are not willing to make an effort to format your question properly, then I cannot help you.